# PythonException -AssertionError raised within the Spark worker

Tags: pyspark, azure-notebooks

For every row in `input_table` there should be created **X** amount of rows in `output_table`, where **X**=days in year (from `StartDate`)

`Info` field should contain **Y** amount of characters, where **Y**= X*2, if there are less, field should be padded with additional `#`  characters.

In `output_table` `AM` and `PM` columns will be filled with `Info` characters in the correct order, so that  each `AM` & `PM` fields will have exactly 1 character.

Here is the code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, StringType, DateType, StructField, StructType, TimestampType, ArrayType

# Connection details for input table
url="..."
user="..."
password="..."
input_table="..."
output_table="..."

# Define schema for input table
input_schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ID2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("StartDate", TimestampType(), True),
    StructField("Info", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Extracted", TimestampType(), True)
])

# Define schema for output table
output_schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID1", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("ID2", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("Date", DateType(), True),
    StructField("AM", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PM", StringType(), True),
    StructField("CurrentYear", StringType(), True)
])

# Initialize SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Register UDF for padding marks
pad_marks_udf = udf(lambda info, days: marks.ljust(days, '#')[:days], StringType())

# Register UDF for creating rows
create_rows_udf = udf(lambda start_date, marks, days: [(start_date + i, info[i], info[i + 1]) for i in range(0, days, 2)],
                     ArrayType(StructType([
                         StructField("Date", DateType(), True),
                         StructField("AM", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("PM", StringType(), True),
                     ])))

# Define function to pad marks and create rows
def process_row(row):
    id1 = row["ID1"]
    id2 = row["ID2"]
    start_date = row["StartDate"]
    info= row["info"]
    extracted = row["Extracted"]

    # Calculate number of days * 2
    days = (start_date.year % 4 == 0 and 366 or 365) * 2

    # Pad info
    padded_info = pad_info_udf(info, days)

    # Create rows
    rows = create_rows_udf(start_date, padded_info, days)

    # Prepare output rows
    output_rows = []
    for r in rows:
        date = r["Date"]
        am = r["AM"]
        pm = r["PM"]
        current_year = f"{current_year .year}/{current_year .year + 1}"

        output_rows.append((id1, id2, date, am, pm, current_year))

    return output_rows

# Load input table as DataFrame
df_input = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", input_table) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .schema(input_schema) \
    .load()

# Apply processing to input table
output_rows = df_input.rdd.flatMap(process_row)

# Create DataFrame from output rows
df_output = spark.createDataFrame(output_rows, output_schema)

# Write DataFrame to output table
df_output.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("dbtable", output_table) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

Similar code works in `Python` with no problems, but when translated to `PySpark` throws an `AssertionError`. It needs to do no modification in `input_table` and append `output_table` with modified rows from `input_table`.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace

Comment: @IslamElbanna done, I have added it as an Error to the description

Comment: pyspark is distributed processing engine and why the code  working in python because there is only process running and creating output. so if you repartition your dataframe to have only 1 partition the pyspark code will also work. I would recommend going through multiple blogs on udf in spark.

Comment: @yogeshgarud thanks for your comment,  but what do you mean? Isn't current code having 1 partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason is that code is not supposed to use Spark UDF in functions for RDDs. The plain functions should be used instead. Spark UDF can only be used in Spark SQL.

The reason the code worked in the local machine is because in the local mode the executor is in the same JVM as the driver.